# issue with upgrading to spring cloud Dalston.SR4 version from Brixton.SR3

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I am trying to upgrade to spring-cloud version from **Brixton.SR3** to **Dalston.SR4** version but somehow the ribbon client is not working properly.

We have a service running with version Brixton.SR3 trying to make a rest cal to another service with version Dalston.SR4 through ribbon. I am not sure why it is broken as the communication between services are restful interface and we dont change any any api call between 2 services

As we have a lot of services are running, so we dont prefer upgrade all services to latest version at once that is why we are upgrading each subset of services.

below is a simple diagram for my situation

[image]

Please help to advise? Thanks

Comment: Are you using ribobn client direclty ? or via Feign or loadbalanced Rest client ?

Comment: I am using loadbalanced Rest client @yongsung.yoon

Comment: You need to check the properties of Http client. From Dalston Release, the default http client of Ribbon was changed from Ribbon internal rest client to apache http client. If you have any properties and configuration for Ribbon rest client, you need to configuration same thing for apache http client. Or just try to change default http client via properties.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have number services running in production with Brixton.SR3 version. Can you advise how to perform rolling upgrade for each MSs to avoid service interuption? @yongsung.yoon

Comment: We've upgraded our servers from Camden to Dalston last year. At that time, first we checked the compatibility of Eureka and Config Server between Camden and Dalson in our test env. And then we checked the server's internal operation like retryable operation by ribbon and any other http operation like connection pool and timeout that can be caused by changes of http client. And then we upgraded our common servers like zuul, eureka, and config server. And then we upgraded eash MSs sequentially. I think that test is the only way for the safe upgrade.